# Comparing word frequencies between two corpora to find keywords

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, statistics

I have a set of tweets that are either labelled as ironic or non-ironic, and have separated them into two different corpora: ironic and non-ironic. I want to compare these two to see which words are the keywords of each corpora, remove them from the tweets and see how this affects irony detection.

So far, I have simply counted the frequency of the words in each corpus and ranked them this way. I have also computed the relative frequency of each word in the ironic corpus, and then compared it with the same word's relative frequency in the non-ironic corpus (and vice versa). This was done by either taking the difference (e.g. the word "love" has a relative frequency of 12 in the ironic corpus, and 5 in the non-ironic corpus, which gives a difference of 7) or the ratio (using the same example: 12 / 7 = 1.7).

However, I have been reading some papers about this, which is making me rethink my method. They mention the following ways of comparing two corpora:

1. Pearson's chi-squared test
2. log-likelihood ratio test
3. Welch’s t-Test
4. Wilcoxon rank-sum test
5. Bootstrap test

Is it best to figure out how to implement these in Python and use one of them instead of comparing the relative frequencies? If so, which ones are suitable to my problem?

Comment: Arent you just looking for (and somewhat describing) tf-idf, in which your sets are the documents?

Comment: @SvanBalen I guess: I want to find e.g. words that are important in the ironic corpus, but unimportant in the non-ironic one. I've now done this by comparing relative frequencies, and I assume you are trying to say I should use tf-idf for this? I think the question will still remain as to whether or not this is a good way of comparing corpora frequencies, or if I should use one of the aforementioned tests instead.